# Kafka scala, Produce from Json

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I need to Kafka produce from Json file, should I write the file path it in properties? and how?

thank you

```scala
val kafkaProducerProps: Properties = {
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  props.put("key.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
  props.put("value.serializer", classOf[StringSerializer].getName)
```

Comment: What do you mean "produce by Json file"? Get the Kafka producer configuration from a JSON file? Or send content of a JSON file to some Kafka topic?

Comment: i meant send content of json file to kafka topic

Comment: Then @OneCricketeer answer is the good one: you have to manually read your JSON file and extract the messages you want to send through Kafka.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot give any JSON files to Kafka properties, it'll only accept `java.util.Properties` objects / key value pairs.

To produce JSON, you need to open/parse the file completely separate from the Kafka API, such as with Play JSON library or Jackson, then construct your KafkaProducer and send the JSON events as strings since that's how you've setup the serializer.